# OpenTok with Cordova error 1013 media resource not suitable

Tags: iphone, cordova, xcode7, cordova-plugins, opentok

I am trying to get bi-directional video chat working on iOS (9.3) with <strike>cordova-plugin-opentokjs (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-opentokjs)</strike> cordova-plugin-iosrtc. I am using cordova 6.3.0 and OpenTok 2.8.1. The problem I am having is that when I start up the video I get an error from the subscriber stream as follows:

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new global.AudioContext()')
[Error] OT.exception :: title: Connection Failed (1013) msg: OT.Subscriber PeerConnection Error: There was an unexpected problem with the Video Stream: The media resource indicated by the src attribute was not suitable.
[Error] No message (2)
[Error] OT.exception :: title: Unexpected Server Response (2001) msg: Unexpected server response. Try this operation again later.
```

The publisher stream works fine... at least I can see myself (but the other user can not see me). Any ideas?

Here is some relevant code:

```
this.onDeviceReady = function() {

  if (window.device.platform === 'iOS') {
    cordova.plugins.iosrtc.registerGlobals();
  }
};
```

And when I goto the video page I do (calling initializeSession):

```
...
initializePublisher: function() {
  var self = this;
  if (Globals.debug) 
    console.log("initializePublisher");

  if (!this.videoInputDevices || this.videoInputDevices.length === 0)
    return;

  var inputDevice = this.videoInputDevices[this.currentVideoDevice];
  if (!inputDevice || !inputDevice.deviceId)
    return;

  var $contianer = $('#openTokVideoContainer .mnOpenTokPublisherContainer');
  $contianer.empty();

  var $div = $('<div id="openTokPublisherStream"></div>');
  $contianer.append($div);

  this.publisher = OT.initPublisher('openTokPublisherStream', {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    fitMode: 'contain',
    videoSource: inputDevice.deviceId,
    mirror: (this.currentVideoDevice === 0)
  });

  this.publisher.on('streamCreated', function(e) {
    var stream = e.stream,
        streamId = stream.streamId,
        $div = $('#openTokVideoContainer .mnOpenTokPublisherContainer > *');

    $div.attr('data-stream', streamId);
    console.log("Publisher stream: ", streamId);
  });

  this.session.publish(this.publisher);
},
initializeSession: function() {
  var config = this.config,
      self = this;

  if (Globals.debug) 
    console.log("initializeSession");

  if (Globals.debug) 
    console.log("INIT SESSION " + config.sessionId + " TOKEN" + config.token);

  this.session = OT.initSession(config.apiKey, config.sessionId);
  this.session.on('streamCreated', function(e) {
    var config = self.config;
    if (Globals.debug) 
      console.log("onSessionConnected");

    self.subscribeToStream(e.stream, 'mnOpenTokSubscriberContainer');

    if (Globals.debug) 
      console.log("Stream created ");
  });

  this.session.on('streamDestroyed', function(e) {
    self.closeAllStreamSubscriptions(e.stream);
  });

  this.session.connect(config.token, function (e) {
    if (!self.publisher) {
      self.getVideoDevices().then(function()  {
        self.initializePublisher();
      });
    }
  });

  if (Globals.debug) 
    console.log("initializeSession");
},...
```

Help?

**Edit: After lots of head banging, plugin updates, etc, I now have it giving me the following errors (and the published video no longer works):**

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new t({type:"offer",sdp:l.content.sdp})')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new u(n.content)')
[Error] OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError TypeError: Unknown Error while getting user media
[Error] OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg: GetUserMedia
[Error] No message (2)
[Error] No message (2)
[Error] OT.exception :: title: Unexpected Server Response (2001) msg: Unexpected server response. Try this operation again later.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when the OpenTok library is included in the index.html at that point in time the WebRTC API is still not registered in the global scope. The OpenTok library should be loaded after the `cordova.plugins.iosrtc.registerGlobals()` is executed.

Use the following script at the end of the body in the index.html to load the OpenTok library dynamically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    // cordova-plugin-device provides the device object
    if (device && device.platform === 'iOS') {
        cordova.plugins.iosrtc.registerGlobals();
    }

    // Insert OpenTok library after the device is ready
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('src', 'https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js');
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  }, false);
</script>
```